# WordPress: Why doesn't custom field checkbox appear in the template, but only its label and instruction

Tags: wordpress, checkbox

I created a custom field group with two fields one of which is a checkbox. The checkbox doesn't appear, but its label and the instruction for the checkbox, so I cannot click the actual checkbox. I don't seem to have missed any setting for the checkbox while creating it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you adda screen grab of the field settings?

Comment: Added the settings from WordPress Admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `choice` for the  checkbox to show.  Add something like:

```
yes : Yes
```

into the Choices `textarea` then save the field set.

Comment: Sweet glad happy that helped!